# How does one import the contents of a text or configuration file innately in a project?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried the following in an `__init__.py` file, thinking that it would be evaluated according to its location at the time of import:

```
# /../../proj_dir_foo/__init__.py
# opens file: .../proj_dir_foo/foo.csv

import pandas as pd
settings = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')
```

And from a different file:

```
from foo.bar.proj_dir_foo import settings
```

Yields: `FileNotFoundError`

---

But this is not really convenient.  Instead of accumulating configuration files that are much easier to modify, I am accumulating source code in `proj_dir_foo` which stores configuration info.

The sole reason it is in source code is because having a project module that knows where the root's resources or materials folder full of configs is *is not technically a* "**module**".  Instead, it is an integrated cog in a machine. Or, rather, a thing I can no longer easily refactor.

---

How does one modularize any arbitrary configuration file in python project?

Comment: Are you specifically looking to do something that the `yaml` or `configparser` do not? If you write configs in "python-eeze" allowing someone to simply `import` it, would that not be a potential security problem? Maybe I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @JonSG security problem? Why does anyone using python concern themselves with that?  It is like bringing a rain coat to a swimming pool :D.   Securing python is like securing Solidworks or Matlab: why? By the time your python code is getting compromised, you have already lost. 

I suppose I am looking for configuration that can live inside a module the same way source code can.

Answer (score 0):

Your script's current directory is the directory from which you started it. `import os; print(os.getcwd())` will show you that.

If you want to open a file what sits in a place relative to your code, you have several options.

Use `sys.argv[0]` to get the path to your script; Use `path.dirname()` to extract the directory from it, and `path.join()` make a path to a particular file:

```py
# some script.
import json, sys, path

my_path = path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
cfg_path = path.join(my_path, 'config', 'settings.json')
with open(my_path) as cfg_file:
  my_settings = json.load(cfg_file)
```

Alternatively, if you import a module, you can use its `__file__` attribute to learn where did you import it from, and use to locate a config:

```py
# some script.
import path
import foo.bar.baz

baz_cfg_path = path.join(path.dirname(foo.bar.baz.__file__), 'baz.cfg')
```

Comment: looks like the second one is the most integrated with the language, but it is still a less mobile resource than source code.